# SQLite giving weird errors when using with typeorm

Tags: sqlite, typeorm

this is my error:

```
DriverPackageNotInstalledError: SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
    at new DriverPackageNotInstalledError (/home/sk0le/projects/authentication/server/src/error/DriverPackageNotInstalledError.ts:8:9)
    at SqliteDriver.loadDependencies (/home/sk0le/projects/authentication/server/src/driver/sqlite/SqliteDriver.ts:135:19)
```

I am using WSL 2.
Sqlite is installed, I checked it. Why is this happening?
I am using TypeORM with typescript to make REST api.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the "sqlite3" npm package into your project?